# How to tidy up this with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, enumeration, collect

I have a String array which I want to convert to specifc format. For example

```
y = ["hello","how","you"]
```

And the output should be the following exact String

```
[["hello","hello"],["how","how"],["you","you"]]
```

I have currently used the following way which is working fine for me, but I need to know is there a better way to do this in Ruby

```
"[#{y.collect {|x| "[#{["\"#{x}\"", "\"#{x}\""].join(",")}]" }.join(",").to_s}]"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use zip for this:

```
y.zip(y).inspect
```

EDIT - just noticed you were after a string - I think inspect should do the job.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = y.zip(y).inspect
puts s
#=> [["hello","hello"],["how","how"],["you","you"]]
```